# Oracle Apex 5 Error, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Can't see missing parenthesis?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have this code, and cannot work out why I am getting issues. Can anyone help? It executes the generate sequence command, but not the create tables one, so I therefore cannot see it on the object browser.

If this helps:

1. QuizID is to be generated by a sequence.
2. QuizTitle, is at most 15 characters, and is not null.
3. Category is to default to *Music* with *Sports* and *Geography* as the only other available options.

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Quiz_NLB_2 
  ( 
   QuizID   NUMBER,
   QuizTitle VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
   Category VARCHAR2(9) DEFAULT 'Music',

   CONSTRAINT pk_QuizID PRIMARY KEY (QuizID),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Category CHECK (Category='Music', 'Sports', 'Geography')

);

CREATE SEQUENCE QuizID_Sequence_Gen START WITH 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check` constraint should look like this:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_Category
    CHECK (Category IN ('Music', 'Sports', 'Geography'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really struggled for quite a while, appreciate the help.